# Converted User file to .exe, now I don't know how to revert it back

Tags: python-3.x, directory, pyinstaller, revert

I've been writing some code in Python, and then I wanted to convert it to .exe file, so I went to Youtube, and searched for tutorial. Then I went to PyCharm Terminal, and I wrote : pyinstaller --onefile -w " "
Exactly like this, but I forgot to put a name between " ", and the process has started, and after it got finished, I can no longer see my User profile in C:\Users.. there is only "Public" left, but before that happened, there was also "matus" profile next to it... I'm not missing any files or anything, but I can't see the "matus" user anymore, and I would like to revert it somehow, but I don't know which code I should use for it.

Answer (score 0):

When using pyinstaller, there should have been folders / files created for the compilation process inside whatever folder you were working in. Try looking in those folders / files for your missing user folder.

Comment: My whole User file has disappeared, even if I change the settings of file explorer to show hidden files, it's not there.. I would need probably some revert code, that could transfer that non-existant .exe to normal user file as it was before.